# Sweet.js expression to string literal

Tags: javascript, macros, sweet.js

I'm trying to write a macro that will convert tokens to strings. My current macro looks like this:

```
macro stringify {
    case {
        $name($token)
    } => {
        letstx $tokenStr = [makeValue(unwrapSyntax(#{$token}), #{here})];
        return #{
            $tokenStr
        }
    }

    case {
        $name($token $rest ... )
    } => {
        return #{
            stringify($token) , stringify($rest ...)
        }
    }
}
```

This works well for turning identifiers into strings, but it fails to turn literals or expressions into strings. Here's my test case and what it compiles into:

```
stringify(a b 7 d e foo 5+9)
```

compiles into:

```
'a', 'b', 7, 'd', 'e', 'foo', 5, '+', 9;
```

I'd like it to compile into:

```
'a', 'b', '7', 'd', 'e', 'foo', '5+9';
```

I assumed I could accomplish this by using the `expr` pattern class, but when I do, I receive this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sweet.js/lib/sweet.js:99
                    throw new SyntaxError(syn.printSyntaxError(source$2, err))
                          ^
SyntaxError: [makeValue] Cannot make value syntax object from: [object Object]
    at expand$2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sweet.js/lib/sweet.js:99:27)
    at parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sweet.js/lib/sweet.js:135:29)
    at Object.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sweet.js/lib/sweet.js:143:19)
    at Object.exports.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sweet.js/lib/sjs.js:70:45)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sweet.js/bin/sjs:7:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10
```

Which appears to be caused by the `makeValue` function being unable to handle an expression.

If anyone could provide me with some insight, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

So `expr`s will be an array of tokens that you'll need to map over.
Simple example:

```
macro str_expr {

    case {
        _ ($toks:expr)
    } => {
        var toks = #{$toks};
        var toks_str = toks.map(function(tok) { return unwrapSyntax(tok); }).join("");
        letstx $tok_str = [makeValue(toks_str, #{here})];
        return #{
             $tok_str
        }
    }
}

str_expr (2 + 4)
// expands to '2+4'
```

You just need to handle the normal token case and the `:expr` cases individually.

Comment: When I run this, it expands into `'[object Object]'`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a modified version of timdiney's answer.

```
macro str_expr {

    case {
        _ ($toks:expr)
    } => {
        var toks = #{$toks};
        var toks_str = unwrapSyntax(toks[0]).inner.map(function(tok) {
            return unwrapSyntax(tok);
        }).join("");

        letstx $tok_str = [makeValue(toks_str, #{here})];
        return #{
             $tok_str
        }
    }
}

console.log(str_expr (2+ 4+7 - 9 + a));
// expands into "2+3+7-9+a"
```